# How to get reactive value into setup() method from composable files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
//Composable file getCollection.js
const getCollection = (collection) => {
    const documents = ref(null)
    const error = ref(null)

    let collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection)
        .orderBy('createdAt')

    const unsub = collectionRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
        let results = []
        console.log('snapshot')
        snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
            doc.data().createdAt && results.push({
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id
            })
        })
        documents.value = results
        error.value = null

    }, (err) => {
        documents.value = null
        error.value = "Could not fetch data"
    })
    watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
        onInvalidate(() => {
            unsub()
        })
    })

    return {
        error,
        documents,
    }
}

export default getCollection
```

Vue Component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="chat-window">
    <div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
    <div v-if="documents" class="messages" ref="messages">
      <div v-for="doc in formattedDocuments" :key="doc.id" class="single">   //Getting all the values perfectly
        <span class="created-at">{{ doc.createdAt }} ago</span>
        <span class="name">{{ doc.name }}</span>
        <span class="message">{{ doc.message }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import getCollection from "../composable/getCollection";
export default {
  setup() {
        const { error, documents} = getCollection("messages");
        
        console.log(error.value) // null 


    return {
      error,
      documents
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am having trouble when I want to access reactive value in `setup()` method from the composable file `getCollection.js` . And, it's showing “null” inside `setup()` method. I can not access values from the `setup()`

```
console.log(error.value) // null 
                         // why is error value null here?
```

But, it’s working perfectly inside template. I am getting all the values of `documents` and `error` from  `template` but not from the `setup()`. How can I get all the values from `setup()` as well?

Comment: Are you able to access documents.value in the setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're logging the value of the `error` `ref` before it's been updated, which happens asynchronously when the data is loaded successfully.

If you want an update whenever `error` changes, you could [`watch`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watching-a-single-source) it:

```js
import { watch } from "vue";
import getCollection from "../composable/getCollection";

export default {
  setup() {
    const { error, documents } = getCollection("messages");

    watch(error, newErrorValue => {
      console.log(newErrorValue);
    })

    return {
      error,
      documents
    }
  }
}
```